# the keyboard python library is not working on MacOS Mojave

Tags: python, ios, macos, keyboard, macos-mojave

When I run this code:

```
import keyboard

def function_that_checks_if_q_is_pressed():
    if keyboard.read_key()=="q":
        print(True)

while True:
    function_that_checks_if_q_is_pressed()
    if function_that_checks_if_q_is_pressed==True:
        break
    break
```

It gives me this error

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 294, in listen
    _os_keyboard.listen(self.direct_callback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keyboard/_darwinkeyboard.py", line 430, in listen
    raise OSError("Error 13 - Must be run as administrator")
OSError: Error 13 - Must be run as administrator
```

On another thread, someone said to run the "sudo command" what does that mean?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The "sudo command" basically just runs a command as administrator
You just type `sudo` followed by the command you would run
In your case it looks like your program is trying to do something requiring administrator access
When running your program try typing

```
 sudo python file.py
```

Hope this solves your problem :)